# Collapsing data case by case in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I'm working with a data set that contains information on anti-human trafficking organizations.  The organizations are identified by either the organization names or the web address of the organization's home page.  I'd like to conditionally collapse this data frame on a case-by-case basis so that I'm left with a unique set of identifiers (in the case of my data, either the name of an organization or the organization's web address) for each case along with about 1000+ numeric attributes for these cases that are either the highest or lowest value of however many rows the identifier was associated with before the collapse.  To exemplify this, I want to turn:

```
> df1
x      y     z
Item1  0     3
Item1  1     4
Item2  1     2
Item3  1     3
Item2  1     5
Item3  1     2
Item4  0     2
```

Into something like

```
> df2
x     y      z
Item1  1     3
Item2  1     2
Item3  1     2
Item4  0     2
```

In this example, of course, I want to keep the max for Var2 and the min for Var3 and preserve only unique Var1 values.

Can anyone suggest a systematic way to do this for a large data set? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(x), summarize, y=max(y), z=min(z))
      x y z
1 Item1 1 3
2 Item2 1 2
3 Item3 1 2
4 Item4 0 2
```

Alternatively, and just about as simple, is the package `data.table`. This option is likely to substantially faster if your data is really large.

```
library(data.table)
data.table(df)[, list(y=max(y), z=min(z)), by=x]
       x y z
1: Item1 1 3
2: Item2 1 2
3: Item3 1 2
4: Item4 0 2
```

Comment: This is very helpful! However I have one (potentially silly) question -  since R tends to "think" in terms of vectors, how reliable will the data.table technique be in preserving the cases or rows of my data.  Let me know if this needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should probably pick Andrie's because he gives you the data.table approach which is arguable cleaner and certainly faster, but the "classical" approach to processing different outcomes within categories is to use `lapply(split(...))`:

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply( split(df1, df1$x) , function (d) data.frame(x=d$x[1], 
                                                          mx.y=max(d$y), mn.z=min(d$z)
             ) ) )

          x mx.y mn.z
Item1 Item1    1    3
Item2 Item2    1    2
Item3 Item3    1    2
Item4 Item4    0    2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plyr)
V1 <- sample(10, 100, replace=TRUE)
V2 <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
V3 <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(V1=V1, V2=V2, V3=V3)

ddply(df, "V1", function(x) c(max(x$V2), min(x$V3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `y` and `z` represent the number of rows and thereby are inherently positive, you could use this simple approach:

```
aggregate(cbind(y, -z) ~ x, df1, function(x) abs(max(x)))

      x y -z
1 Item1 1  3
2 Item2 1  2
3 Item3 1  2
4 Item4 0  2
```